# Android Studio Build stuck when minifyEnabled is true

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio Generate Signed Apk stuck at

```
app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardRelease
ExcecuteTransform
```

it works when minifyEnabled is false

My app.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ashishclasses"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
//    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation "com.vimeo.networking:vimeo-networking:1.1.3"
//    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
//    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:9.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I even removed all my proguard rules, Now proguard-rules.pro is just empty file

Please tell me how I can build apk while proguard enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept running my build and after 20 Minutes Finally

```
Gradle build finished in 20 m 45 s 428 ms
```

So kind of my problem is solved but not actually.

My simple build of signed apk takes 1-2 minutes and with minify enabled 20+ minutes

And my hardware's are not that bad,

I have 6gb ram and ssd and using on arch linux and AMD A8 processor